# How to put a div between two different backgrounds

Tags: html, css

I want to put a div between two different backgrounds.
It looks something like below image:

[image]

As you can see, the div placed in between two background, white and blue.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use stripe images as background

Comment: Post your code with some demo

Comment: please show your markup and css, this can be done with a simple background colour and a navigation overlapped with a box-shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` and a negative `margin-top` on the `div` you want in the middle

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tinmarin60/wfrxcg8h/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code by applying to that div. In this code you can use two different colors to background that you want.

```
background: linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 50%, #008ED3 50%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 50%, #008ED3 50%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 50%, #008ED3 50%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 50%, #008ED3 50%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 50%, #008ED3 50%);
```

In above code do not remove any single line, because each line is for browser compatibility, each line code is for different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can position your white div so that it stacks on top of the divs with blue and white background.

https://jsfiddle.net/z6ohochn/

```
#blue {
    background: blue;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
}
#white {
    width:80%;a
    height:50px;
    background:white;
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
    top:-80px;
    left:10%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#gray {
    background: gray;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
}
```